# Iframe origin error in Safari due to CSS rule

Tags: css, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have replicated an error as shown below in Safari:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "thepagedomain" from accessing a frame with origin "theiframesourcedomain". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

With the following very simple page:

```
<html><head>
<style>
#iframe{
    
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 49px);

    
}
</style>        
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://test.com/" id="iframe"></iframe>   
</body>
</html>
```

Where the content of the iframe is in this case empty, usually it has a full page.

The weird thing this error goes away if the width or height percentages are set below 90%.

I assume this is some kind of bug and nothing to worry about but is there anything I can do to suppress the error as it is confusing things with other genuine errors of this kind.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior - could you put up a snippet which definitely shows the problem, and it going away when you alter the CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That really is all the code that is producing the problem.

Comment: With that exact same iframe src? [I realise that an actual SO snippet will probably not recreate things properly in this case because of its being an iframe so just the code will do]

Comment: The src is a subdomain of the parent window's domain, it is an allowed frame-src according to the CORS settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding a sandbox like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 49px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://test.com/" id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Safari's handling of iframe sizing and cross-origin content may be causing the issue. If an iframe is set to 100% width and height, Safari may not accurately calculate its content's size, resulting in the cross-origin error.

Is that possible to write styles in px? like that for example

will you be seeing an error?

```
<iframe src="https://test.com/" id="iframe" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: That's no an option unfortunately.